# Django referrer get short domain in template

Tags: python, django

I save visits referrer address on db. But It save like this

```
domain.com/domainurl_page1.php
```

I want to delete after from .com, How can i cut domain like this ;

```
domain.com
```

i call referrers list in template;

```
{% for i in get_all_referer %}

       {{ i.referer }}

{% endfor %}
```

my view.py

```
ref = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'Direct')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `urlparse`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
parsed_url = urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'Direct'))
result = parsed_url.netloc
```

However, `urlparse` requires a scheme for it to work, e.g. `https://example.com` instead of just `example.com`.

EDIT: You need to change the string "Direct" to a valid URL.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its work! I'm just curious Is there a way to do this from the template section?

Comment: You'll need to create a custom template tag for that.

Comment: You can also just pass a function to your template.

Comment: Can you explain to me with an easy example? Thanks a lot!